# working command in terminal doesn't work if automatically executed at startup

Tags: startup, autostart, startup-applications

I need to execute a python program at Ubuntu startup.
The script works either run from visual studio code, or from the terminal with the command:

```
bash -c "python3 /home/complete_path/script.py"
```

Nevertheless, if I put the same code using the "startup applications", the code is run but it gives back an error.
In order to understand what's going on, I tried many other methods in order to run the file such as modifying local.rc use service or crontab but the result is always the same.
I tried also to automatically launch the terminal and execute the command at terminal startup but the result is not changed.
Which kind of differences are there in a command run at startup or automatically by a terminal vs
manually inserting them? I cannot figure out what's going on.

The system is a Jetson nano with Ubuntu 18.04 installed.

**EDIT 1**
running it as a service it seems that it cannot import a python module

```
-- Automatic restarting of the unit mything.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
gen 18 15:56:33 aisports-desktop systemd[1]: Stopped mything: do my own thing.
-- Subject: Unit mything.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mything.service has finished shutting down.
gen 18 15:56:33 aisports-desktop systemd[1]: Started mything: do my own thing.
-- Subject: Unit mything.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mything.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
gen 18 15:56:33 aisports-desktop mything.sh[7800]: Traceback (most recent call last):
gen 18 15:56:33 aisports-desktop mything.sh[7800]:   File "/home/aisports/Desktop/AISports/RGB_control_camera.py", line 11, in <module>
gen 18 15:56:33 aisports-desktop mything.sh[7800]:     import depthai as dai
gen 18 15:56:33 aisports-desktop mything.sh[7800]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'depthai'
gen 18 15:56:33 aisports-desktop systemd[1]: mything.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
gen 18 15:56:33 aisports-desktop systemd[1]: mything.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

while I still cannot find the log of crontab, since the command

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

gives back

```
Binary file /var/log/syslog matches
```

**EDIT 2**
I solved the missing module problem adding the path of that module at top of the python script through

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path_to_module')
```

now the problem that occurs is the same as in case of startup applications:

```
gen 18 18:08:31 aisports-desktop systemd[1]: Stopped mything: do my own thing.
-- Subject: Unit mything.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mything.service has finished shutting down.
gen 18 18:08:31 aisports-desktop systemd[1]: Started mything: do my own thing.
-- Subject: Unit mything.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mything.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
gen 18 18:08:32 aisports-desktop mything.sh[7763]: [2022-01-18 18:08:32.050] [warning] VideoEncoder setDefaultProfilePreset: passing 'width'/ 'height' is deprecated. The size is auto-determined from first
gen 18 18:08:34 aisports-desktop mything.sh[7763]: Stack trace (most recent call last):
gen 18 18:08:34 aisports-desktop mything.sh[7763]: #2    Object "/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1", at 0x7fb4f57a33, in
gen 18 18:08:34 aisports-desktop mything.sh[7763]: #1    Object "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/../../numpy.libs/libopenblasp-r0-32ff4d91.3.13.so", at 0x7fa055772b, in gotoblas_init
gen 18 18:08:34 aisports-desktop mything.sh[7763]: #0    Object "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/../../numpy.libs/libopenblasp-r0-32ff4d91.3.13.so", at 0x7fa06d4f54, in gotoblas_dynamic_
gen 18 18:08:34 aisports-desktop mything.sh[7763]: Illegal instruction (Illegal opcode [0x7fa06d4f54])
gen 18 18:08:35 aisports-desktop mything.sh[7763]: /usr/local/bin/mything.sh: line 2:  7779 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) python3 /home/aisports/Desktop/AISports/RGB_control_camera.py
gen 18 18:08:35 aisports-desktop systemd[1]: mything.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=132/n/a
gen 18 18:08:35 aisports-desktop systemd[1]: mything.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

**EDIT 3 (last)**
I finally solved the problem.
in .bashrc file I had added `export OPENBLAS_CORETYPE=ARMV8` because of the type of the processor. I though that was sufficient also for the startup commands, instead it was not. Adding that line to the startup script, before calling the python script solved the problem.
Thank you @FelixJN for the support on having the log files, that helped me a lot.

Comment: Does the script rely on some environment? E.g. display (does it start some GUI?), network connection, etc.? What did `systemd` or `cron` report in the logs when failing?

Comment: the script basically acquire a video from a usb camera, save it in h265, do a conversion in mp4 compressing it through gstreamer ando so on.  No GUI and no display. The only thing that is called outside is the gstreamer conversion through pexpect.

Comment: And `python3` is installed where? Might this just be a `PATH` problem? Please add the error messages for your `CRON` and `systemd` implementations.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't know where to find those logs.
The error that appear in syslog file when launched with startup application is the following:
#2    Object "/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1", at 0x7fad741a33, in
#1    Object "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/../../numpy.libs/libopenblasp-r0-32ff4d91.3.13.so", at 0x7fa14da72b, in gotoblas_init
#0    Object "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/../../numpy.libs/libopenblasp-r0-32ff4d91.3.13.so", at 0x7fa1657f54, in gotoblas_dynamic_init
Illegal instruction (Illegal opcode [0x7fa1657f54])
Illegal instruction

Comment: Please do not add this as comment - [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1387746/edit) your question and add the info (with proper code formatting). `CRON` messages can be found in `syslog` (`grep CRON /var/log/syslog`), `systemd` info via `journalctl -xeu <servicename>` (add `--user` if it is a user service).

Comment: ok, I will do it in few minutes. I found out that the same problem appears also if the code is launched by terminal with sudo. I don't know if it helps

Comment: I edited the question, but still no idea on what is going on

Comment: It's a question of "execution context". Your terminal execution of the script runs as you (` echo "$USER"`) has the benefit of your startup files, `PATH` and other environment variables for Python. The system startup process runs as `root`, doesn't use your startup files, has its own `PATH`, and none of your environment variables. Run `echo "=== id ===";id;echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.